# Community a member for 4+ years

Tags: bug

On the [community bot](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=topactivity) profile it says that it was created 4 years and 4 months ago even though this site is only about an hour old.

[image]

Comment: Related post on meta.SE: [Why is the Community user listed on two brand-new sites as having been a member for 3 years and 11 months?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376085/why-is-the-community-user-listed-on-two-brand-new-sites-as-having-been-a-member)

Comment: @HenryWHHackv3.0 thanks for pointing that out. No solution thought.